# Concatenation of String and int types (on declaration!)

Tags: c++

I wanted to give an unique ID number equal to the times an object of class ship has been created
therefore I tried this code I knew from java (but it doesn't work unfortunately)

Name is inherited by parent class vehicle
I would like an implementation that works in GNU c++ compiler (and declaration only)

```
#include <iostream>
static int id = 0;

class Ship:private Vehicle
{
    Ship()
    {
        id++;
        this->name="Pirate"+id;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of name?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// C++98

Ship() {
  std::ostringstream tmp;
  tmp << "Pirate" << ++id;
  name = tmp.str();
}

// C++11

Ship() : name("Pirate" + std::to_string(++id)) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

If data member name has type `std::string` then you can write

```
this->name = "Pirate" + std::to_string( id );
```

Comment: You mean `this->name`, not `this.name`. I tried to edit but it's only 2 characters.

Comment: @zmb I meant the copy and paste.:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow The correct is this->name instead of this.name because C++ considers classes as structs and class fields are like struct members?

Comment: @niCk It is because in C++ this means a pointer to an instance of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert int to string first. Replace `id` with `std::to_string(id)`.